# How to find a masterEdition PDA in Metaplex fixed-price-sale

Tags: metaplex

I'm currently trying to [initialize a selling resource](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/fixed-price-sale/tech-description#initsellingresource) and can't get past the masterEdition attribute.

[image]

Whenever I try to fetch the masterEdition PDA using the referenced seeds [“metadata”, tokenMetadataProgramID, resource_mint, “edition”] I get following error: `TypeError: Max seed length exceeded`

This is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
  const [masterEdition] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
      Buffer.from('metadata'),
      Buffer.from('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s'),
      Buffer.from('5JdQ2GsY5dKeGtAw941bb8Kp5UKi3yZV2PkMfjyHX35a'),
      Buffer.from('edition')
    ],
    toPublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s')
  )
```

I'm assuming the error it's because the seed is to long but how can I do if that's the required seed? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
          [
            Buffer.from("metadata"),
            TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
            mint.toBuffer(),
            Buffer.from("edition"),
          ],
          TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
        )
```

`Buffer.from()`is only used for strings, for pubkeys use `toBuffer()`